# Excel 2013 chart in Excel 2016 - all chart elements disappear when I change the secondary axis

Tags: excel, charts, axis

I have a number of charts created in Excel 2013, but have now upgraded to Excel 2016.They have a number of stacked area series with a line on the secondary axis.

When I try to amend the bounds of the secondary axis, all chart elements disappear, series, axes, legend. If I create a chart in 2016 I can amend them.

I have 30+ charts to update, each takes half an hour upwards to recreate, and this is just one model of many.

What do I need to do to fix them?

I tried deleting the axis then add it again but the same happened. I also tried making all series on the primary axis then making them secondary axis again and they all disappeared.

So I thought I'd try to delete the line on the secondary axis and add it. When I select the series and click (or press) delete, that series stays but all the others disappear. Doesn't matter which axis they are on. But I got round that by deleting using the 'Select data' dialog.

When I deleted the line and added it and tried to make it secondary axis, everything went blank again.

Is there some setting I need to tweak?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots of before & after as well as what you're doing to the secondary axis.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I can't access sharing sites to post them. All I cna say is at first it looked like a regular chart with series, axis labels, legend and data labels. All I did was edit the secondary axis and increase the upper bound from 250 to 300. But it didn't matter what I changed upper or lower bounds too. The result as soon as I hit return is a white box with some horizontal gridlines. I can cycle through the elments using Atlt-cursor but nothing gets selected.